# Will the following code limit the carousel to only the Homepage?

Tags: header, carousel

Our header is a carousel and only appears on the homepage. We'd like it to top every page. at present it only apppears on the homepage. In the code it has the below reference. Not sure how it should read to allow it to be seen on top of all site pages.

[www.crowboroughtennis.co.uk](http://www.crowboroughtennis.co.uk)

```
`<?php 
if(!$cat && !$pid) { //homepage only
include('inc.carousel.php'); 
}else{
include('inc.logoStrip.php');
}
?>
```